# Why won't the floppy mount?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, floppy, opensuse-11.2

The 1.44Meg floppy won't mount in my Nautilus file browser. When I try to mount it, it says there is no media in the drive. Yet, I can write to the floppy through the terminal using the 'cp' command. I can enter the command: `mount -t ext2 /floppy` and it mounts. I have also run a check and the disk itself is 100% clean.

So, why can't I get the nautilus browser to open up the floppy? Is there a way to see the actual floppy from the terminal?

EDIT: So that everyone can satisfy their curiousity - I am trying to boot from a floppy. My own bootstrap and image.

> so it mounts and you can view the file
>   contents in the terminal, right? and
>   after it's mounted you can navigate
>   there in nautilus? or you can't find
>   the mountpoint? i'm not sure what
>   you're asking.

I was trying: `mount -t ext2 /dev/fd0 /floppy`
what I realized is that I had the `/floppy` directory *not* under /media. So I moved the directory to /media/floppy. Once I mounted it the correct way, I got a floppy icon in my nautilus browser where I could see the contents. So, why is there an actual floppy drive icon if I can't click on it and see the floppy contents?

Comment: Who still uses floppies?

Comment: I started laughing as soon as I saw the question. I second @Josh -- may I recommend a USB flash drive? (Added lolwut tag and upvoted the question.)

Comment: There are still ways to get stuck with one, right?

Comment: @dboarman: so it mounts and you can view the file contents in the terminal, right?  and after it's mounted you can navigate there in nautilus?  or you can't find the mountpoint?  i'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to recover data from the floppy just this once or are you actually trying use floppies for storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have apparently been able to get the floppy to mount:

> mount -t ext2 /dev/fd0 /media/floppy

I also had to add an entry to my /etc/fstab file. This seems to have fixed the mounting problems I was having. However, I would still like to be able to see the floppy's directory. If I give the command:

> dir /media/floppy

I get the contents. But this doesn't necessarily give me a warm fuzzy about whether the disk truly has the contents I desire. So if there is a way to confirm the contents of the disk, let me know.